# how to display the the selected cell value to textbox1 and textbox2?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

[image]

I have converted the fare field in gridview1 to display fare | seats in same cell as displayed below...

i want when user select/ click on Book button row then the fare amount will be diplayed in textbox1 and seats will displayed in Textbox2

```
Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Textbox1.text=GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(6).TextToString
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at using [String.Split Method (Char())](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)